# Return error if table has 0 rows in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, validation, sqlite

I want to do a post-validation process for a database build, which creates table schemas and bulk load a few TSVs every night. I want to validate that the bulk load process is actually successful, so I want to check if each table is not empty (with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` > 0), and returns an error if it is empty.

Is it a way to do that? Or any workarounds or validation strategies?

Much appreciated!

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the comment. The build process is actually creating a SQL script `schema.sql`, that contains the schemas for several tables, and bulk load those TSVs (`.import <table_name>.tsv table_name`). This process is finished in an SQLite client CLI (`.read schema.sql`). My current idea is to run another SQL script `validation.sql` to check every table in the database is not empty. But I am not sure if this is the right way and how to implement it. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: That's much clearer. Can you [edit] your post and explain it there instead of in comments? It helps future users of the site who are looking for a solution to a problem if they can clearly see what this question is asking, and it also makes the content searchable (comments are not). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the select command from the command line and then evaluate the result using whatever shell you are using.  See this example.

**Create a table**

```
> sqlite3 test.db

PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Price INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(1,'Audi',52642);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400);
INSERT INTO "Cars" VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600);
COMMIT;
```

**Bash script to test if table `Cars` is empty**

```
if [ "`sqlite3 test.db 'select count(*) from Cars;'`" != "0" ]
then
   echo "Not empty"
fi
```

**Results in**

```
Not empty
```

Of course, you can replace `echo "Not empty"` with `exit 1` to exit the script and raise an error.